# Does extern template prevent inlining of functions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm not entirely clear on how the new `extern template` feature is meant to work in C++11.  I understand that it is intended to help speed up compilation time, and simplify linking issues with shared libraries.  Does that mean that the compiler does not even parse the function body, forcing a non-inlined call to be made?  Or does it simply instruct the compiler to not generate an actual method body when a non-inlined call is made?  Obviously, link-time code generation not withstanding.

As a concrete example of where the difference might matter, consider a function that operates on an incomplete type.

```
//Common header
template<typename T>
void DeleteMe(T* t) {
    delete t;
}

struct Incomplete;
extern template void DeleteMe(Incomplete*);

//Implementation file 1
#include common_header
struct Incomplete { };
template void DeleteMe(Incomplete*);

//Implementation file 2
#include common_header
int main() {
   Incomplete* p = factory_function_not_shown();
   DeleteMe(p);
}
```

Within "Implementation file 2", it is unsafe to `delete` a pointer to `Incomplete`.  So an inlined version of `DeleteMe` would fail.  But if it is left as an actual function call, and the function itself were generated within "Implementation file 1", everything will work correctly.

As a corollary, are the rules the same for member functions of templated classes with a similar `extern template class` declaration?

For experimental purposes, MSVC produces the correct output to the above code, but if the `extern` line is removed generates a warning about deleting an incomplete type.  However, this is the remnants of a non-standard extension they introduced years ago so I'm not sure how much I can trust this behavior.  I don't have access to any other build environments to experiment on [save ideone et al, but being limited to one translation unit is rather limiting in this case].

Comment: +1 for a question that I didn't fully understand for the _right_ reasons. Refreshing.

Comment: I like the question because I don't found a useful and elegant use cases for this C++11 feature in real world projects and I'm hoping to get inspired by the discussion.

Answer (score 8):

The idea behind extern templates is to make explicit template instantiations more useful.

As you know, in C++03, you can explicitly instantiate a template using this syntax:

```
template class SomeTemplateClass<int>;
template void foo<bool>();
```

This tells the compiler to instantiate the template in the current translation unit. However, this doesn't stop implicit instantiations from happening: the compiler still has to perform all implicit instantiations and then merge them together again during linking.

Example:

```
// a.h
template <typename> void foo() { /* ... */ }

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
template void foo<int>();

// b.cpp
#include "a.h"
int main()
{
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `a.cpp` explicitly instantiates `foo<int>()`, but once we go to compile `b.cpp`, it will instantiate it again because `b.cpp` has no idea that `a.cpp` is going to instantiate it anyway. For large functions with many different translation units doing implicit instantiations, this can add quite significantly to compile and link time. It may also cause the function to be unnecessarily inlined, which can lead to significant code bloat.

With extern templates, you can let other source files know that you plan to instantiate the template explicitly:

```
// a.h
template <typename> void foo() { /* ... */ }
extern template void foo<int>();
```

This way, `b.cpp` won't cause an instantiation of `foo<int>()`. The function will be instantiated in `a.cpp` and will be linked like any normal function. It's also much less likely to be inlined.

Note that this doesn't *prevent* inlining -- the function could still be inlined at link time in exactly the same way that a normal non-inline function can still be inlined.

EDIT: For those that are curious, I just did a quick test to see how much time g++ spends instantiating templates. I tried instantiating `std::sort<int*>` in a varying number of translation units, with and without the instantiation being suppressed. The result was conclusive: **30ms per instantiation of std::sort**. There's definitely time to be saved here in a large project.

Comment: Note that in C++03, when you use explicit template specialization, you can declare only the interface in the header and leave the implementation in the cpp file. The drawback of doing this is that any attempt to use a non-specialized version of the template will result in a link error.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand that there will not be an actual function `foo<int>()` in any object file except the one you specify. But does the compiler have the option of dropping the code directly in place without technically generating that function body?  I see that you say it is much less likely to be inlined, but is that because it can't [until link time], or because that is just the way compilers are currently written?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you put the body of the template in a separate TU then the compiler cannot inline it, but the linker can. The reason for this is because compilers compile source files separately, completely independently of other source files, so they simply don't know what the body of the function looks like and therefore can't inline it. I believe compilers are sometimes able to do it if you compile all the source files at once (in one run of the compiler), but I don't know the details on that.

Comment: @ Dennis Zickefoose: separation of compiler and linker is virtual, not necessary physical. Code generation occurs both at compile and link time. In Visual Studio, there is an option for full program optimization for that.

Comment: @PeterAlexander thanks for a good answer, this has been bugging me for a while. For the more curious, could you elaborate on how you measured g++ template-instantiation time - was it any more fine-grained than timing the whole compilation?

Comment: @boycy: I just measured the whole compilation time, including linking, but the results had essentially zero variation. Every additional instantiation added nearly exactly 30ms with incredible consistency.

Comment: IMHO the answer is totally off-topic and it is not the OP asked for.  The OP asked whether compiler is allowed, in principle, to do the inline if it sees the function body in the TU but declared as `extern template`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `extern template class` does not seem to prevent inlining. I will illustrate this via an example, it is a bit involved but the simplest I can come up with.

In file a.h we define template class `CFoo`,

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class CFoo{
  public: CFoo(){
      std::cout << "CFoo Constructor, edit 0" << std::endl;
    }
};

extern template class CFoo<int>;
#endif
```

At the end of a.h we use `extern template class CFoo<int>` to indicate to any translation unit with `#include a.h` that it does not need to generate any code for CFoo. It's a promise we make that all things CFoo will link smoothly.

In file c.cpp we have,

```
#include "a.h"

void run(){
  CFoo<int> cf;
}
```

Due to the `extern template class` `promise' at the end of  a.h, the translation unit of c.cpp does not`need to' generate any code for class CFoo.

Finally we declare a main function in b.cpp,

```
void run();
int main(){
  run();
  return 0;
}
```

There is nothing fancy in b.cpp, we simply declare `void run()` which will be linked to the implementation of the translation unit b.cpp at link-time. For completeness, here is a makefile

```
cflags = -std=c++11 -O1

b : b.o a.o c.o
  g++ ${cflags} b.o a.o c.o -o b

b.o : b.cpp 
  g++ ${cflags} -c b.cpp -o b.o

c.o : c.cpp 
  g++ ${cflags} -c c.cpp -o c.o

a.o : a.cpp a.h
  g++ ${cflags} -c a.cpp -o a.o

clean:
  rm -rf a.o b.o c.o b
```

Using this makefile compiles and links an executable *a* which outputs ``CFoo Constructor, edit 0'' when run. But note! In the example above we do not seem to have declared `CFoo<int>` anywhere : `CFoo<int>` is definitely not declared on translation unit b.cpp as the header does not appear on that translation unit, and translation unit c.cpp was told that it didn't need to implement CFoo. So what's going on?

Make one change to the makefile : replace -O1 with -O0, and make clean  make

Now, the link call results in an error (using gcc 4.8.4)

```
c.o: In function `run()':
c.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `CFoo<int>::CFoo()'
```

This is the error which we would expect if there were no inlining in the first place. At least this is the conclusion I come to, further ideas are very welcome.

To get linking with -O1, we need to keep our promise and provide an implementation of CFoo, this we provide in file a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
template void foo<int>();
```

We can now be guaranteed that CFoo appears on the translation unit of a.cpp, and our promise will be kept. As an aside, note that  `template void foo<int>()` in a.cpp in preceded by `extern template void foo<int>()` via the inclusion of a.h, which is not problematic.

Finally, I find this unpredictable optimisation dependent behaviour annoying, as it means that modifications to a.h and recompilation of a.cpp might not be reflected in `run()` as expected if there were no inlining (try changing standard output of Foo constructor and remake).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting example :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

extern template class std::basic_string<char>;
int foo(std::string s)
{
    int res = s.length();
    res += s.find("some substring");
    return res;
}
```

When compiled with g++-7.2 at -O3, this produces a non-inlined call to string::find BUT an inlined call to string::size.

While without the extern template, everything is indeed inlined. Clang has the same behaviour and MSVC is almost unable to inline anything in any case.

So the anwser is : it depends, and compilers may have special heuristics for this.